# How can I use command on Xamarin Shell Tabbar

Tags: xamarin, tabbar, xamarin.shell

I bought this template and i want to use Command or Clicked event on tab section. When I clicked the tab it goes to the page but page created at once while program is on but i want to make control each time when page created. How can i use Command or Clicked event on tabbar.

```
    <Tab Title="{x:Static res:AppResources.Home}" Route="home"  >
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.Home}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}"   />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="{x:Static res:AppResources.Cart}" Route="cart" >
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.ShoppingCart}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CartPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="{x:Static res:AppResources.MyAccount}" Route="myaccount">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialOutlined" Glyph="{x:Static md:Icons.Person}" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}" />
    </Tab>

</TabBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a property changed event to the tabbar. Such as:

```
private void TabBar_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabbar = sender as TabBar;
        if(tabbar.CurrentItem.TabIndex == 0)
        {
            
        }else if (tabbar.CurrentItem.TabIndex == 1)
        {
          
        }
    }
```

In the shell.xaml:

```
<TabBar PropertyChanged="TabBar_PropertyChanged">
```